# NebulaGraph Database: how to query the COMMENT of TAG and EDGE

Tags: nebula-graph

DESCRIBE can query the detailed information of SPACE, TAG, EDGE

DESCRIBE TAG can only query the COMMENT of the TAG property；
DESCRIBE EDGE can only query the COMMENT of the EDGE property；
And DESCRIBE SPACE can only query the COMMENT of SPACE。

So i want to know how to check the COMMENT of TAG and EDGE? As shown in the picture, I want to check the player's COMMENT.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `show create tag player`
[image: show create tag player]

The same for edges. See https://docs.nebula-graph.io/master/3.ngql-guide/7.general-query-statements/6.show/5.show-create-tag-edge/